# Saving breezejs entities with child/related entities populated to save in a single transaction scope

Tags: json, entity-framework, knockout.js, asp.net-web-api, breeze

I'm trying to save a breezejs entity which has a collection of entities within it, a selection of 'choices' if you will.

something crudely like

```
public class Form{
  public class Choice{
    public string Name {get;set;} 
    public bool Selected {get;set;}
  }
  [Key]
  public Guid Id{get;set;}
  public ICollection<Choice> Choices{get;set;}
}
```

When breezejs saves the changes to the entities it batches them out to respective odata controllers, one for "Form" and one for "Choice".  This would be fine, but I want/need to make the change within a transaction on the server - so ideally I would be able to get a Form model in the Form odata controller which has a collection of Choices populated within it.  Then I can make my changes within a single transaction scope.

I spent a few hours digging, but I can't find a way to ask breezejs to 'embed' the collection of 'Choices' within the 'Form' to get a single Post with a fully populated 'Form' model.

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The current server side OData controllers from MS don't really support transactions involving multiple entity type saves. ( This is a known MS issue, but they have been very slow to address it. )

However, breeze's standard WebApi controller does handle transactions involving multiple entity type saves.  And providing that you are using EF, the transition between the two is relatively simple.

See: 
http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/odata-vs-webapi and

http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/aspnet-web-api